# Что включает в себя слово-понятие "крыльцо"?

Tags: лексика

Что есть крыльцо? В обязательном порядке как-то выделенное место посредством ступеней, козырька, иных элементов пред входом в здание? Может быть, что, например, крыльцом называется просто пространство, местность у входа в здание, и на сколько оно тянется? А может ли им быть смежное с помещением пространство, можно ли, выходя из комнаты, оказываться на крыльце комнаты, и в таком случае фатера будет содержать несколько крылец? Ведь же не только в форме единственного числа употребляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно точно крыльцом не называется никак не выделенное пространство. Иначе нельзя было бы сказать "этот вход - без крыльца".

Викисловарь [говорит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%BE), что "крыльцо" образовано от слова "крыло" - возможно, потому что крыльцо должно (было) быть накрытым чем-либо - навесом, крышей.

На практике же наблюдал, что крыльцом называют всевозможные конструкции на входе, но при соблюдении некоторых условий:

- вход ведет прямо на улицу (открытое пространство)
- на входе есть хоть какая-нибудь конструкция, хотя бы ступенька
- эта конструкция не называется как-то иначе (например, веранда)